# $(gridID).yiiGridView('getChecked', columnID) returning empty array

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii, yii-components, yii2-basic-app

I just want to store the ids of the ticket items, when I check the console I'm just getting an empty array. any idea why?

Yii doc on CCheckBoxColumn states:

> You may also call the JavaScript function
>   $(gridID).yiiGridView('getChecked', columnID) to retrieve the key
>   values of the checked rows.

So I have:

```
 $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.BsGridView', array(
    'id' => 'audits-lines-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $auditlines->search($model->audit_id),
    'filter' => $auditlines,
    'selectableRows' => 2,
    'columns' => array(

        array(
        'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn', 'selectableRows' => 2,
        'id' => 'selected-checkboxes',
        'value' => 'CHtml::tag("span", array("class" => "$data->statusLabel"), "$data->status", "</span>")',
        'name' => 'CHtml::tag("span", array("class" => "$data->statusLabel"), "$data->status", "</span>")',
        ), 
        (some more code here..)
```

and I'm trying to get the checked value with

```
<script>
        $(document).on('click','#block-change-location',function(){
            var items = $('#audits-lines-grid').yiiGridView('getChecked', '#selected-checkboxes')
            console.log(items);
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Try `$.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection(gridID);` or `var id = $.fn.yiiGridView.getChecked("your-grid-id", "selected-checkboxes");`

Comment: thanks Insane Skull, var id = $.fn.yiiGridView.getChecked("your-grid-id", "selected-checkboxes"); worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$.fn.yiiGridView.getChecked("your-grid-id", "selected-checkboxes");
```